# How to paste long text in UITextView

Tags: iphone, ios

How can i paste long text in UITexView because i have static text data. If i try to paste directly in to textView.text, it shows errors. How this can be managed. Please guide.
Thanks in advance.

```
txtView.txt = @"About us

myventr.co is a web-based tool for event creation, event searching and online ticket      selling whilst also serving as a social media network. myventr.co is not just about creating events and buying tickets online but is also a place for you to socialise. You can create your own profile, connect with friends or create your own group for your organisation!

How is this different to other social media websites then? Myevent is about connecting people’s social lives and events all at the same place.  myventr.co will help find all the event details around your location and will also help avoid events clashing by simply searching the Event Calendar before creating an event.";
```

Above is the way i am trying.

Comment: @HinataHyuga unexpected@in program and missing terminating character.

Comment: which type of error u getting :)

Comment: are you entering new line in that?

Comment: Just assign your About us... string to NSString object , then pass that string object to txtview.text.let me know working or not!!!

Comment: Which error are you exactly getting can u please explain

Comment: @Divz error:unexpected@in program warning:missing terminating character

Comment: do you give enter after "About us" or given space using space bar in between myevent.co? because if you give spaces it couldn't give any error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use text in next line instead use '\n' for new line.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot paste a text like that in different lines, if you want to have different lines you'll need to set them yourself with \n.

For example:

```
@"This is line1\nThis is line 2"
```

Answer (score 4):

If you set it programmatically you have to set it in one line:

```
txtView.text = @"About us\n\nmyevent.co is a web-based tool for event creation, event searching and online ticket selling whilst also serving as a social media network. myevent.co is not just about creating events and buying tickets online but is also a place for you to socialise. You can create your own profile, connect with friends or create your own group for your organisation!\n\nHow is this different to other social media websites then? Myevent is about connecting people’s social lives and events all at the same place.  myevent.co will help find all the event details around your location and will also help avoid events clashing by simply searching the Event Calendar before creating an event.";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
txtView.txt = @"About us\n myevent.co is a web-based tool for event creation, event searching and online ticket selling whilst also serving as a social media network. myevent.co is not just about creating events and buying tickets online but is also a place for you to socialise. You can create your own profile, connect with friends or create your own group for your organisation! \nHow is this different to other social media websites then? Myevent is about connecting people’s social lives and events all at the same place.  myevent.co will help find all the event details around your location and will also help avoid events clashing by simply searching the Event Calendar before creating an event.";
```

The error which you are getting is coz of enters you have given in your string. Hence, compiler is not able to understand the end of your statement.

Answer (score 1):

add property file  'about.plist'

```
NSDictionary *dic=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"about" ofType:@"plist"]];
NSLog(@"%@",dic);
```

Comment: Jain can you tell me how to add to plist, i am trying the way by making text file added in to project. how to add in plist?

Comment: 1. Right Click on Files in Left Pane and Select 'New File...' option.
2. Choose Resources from OS X tab.
3. An option for Property List is available.
4. Select an give an appropriate name.

This gets added to your project.

Answer (score 1):

Set it directly in XIB. That can handle the text automatically with new line.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write the text on multiple lines you can add a `\` character at the end of each line.

```
txtView.txt = @"About us\

myevent.co is a web-based tool for event creation, event searching and online ticket      selling whilst also serving as a social media network. myevent.co is not just about creating events and buying tickets online but is also a place for you to socialise. You can create your own profile, connect with friends or create your own group for your organisation!\

How is this different to other social media websites then? Myevent is about connecting people’s social lives and events all at the same place.  myevent.co will help find all the event details around your location and will also help avoid events clashing by simply searching the Event Calendar before creating an event.";
```

Answer (score 1):

I try your code found you given enter in string where you need space use new (\n) line char where required space as other answers suggested.I follow your code replace Enter with spaces its working.Try it. It is Suggested to use new line char for new line.

```
UITextView *textView=[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 50, 320, 300)];
textView.text = @"About us                                                                                         myventr.co is a web-based tool for event creation, event searching and online ticket      selling whilst also serving as a social media network. myventr.co is not just about creating events and buying tickets online but is also a place for you to socialise. You can create your own profile, connect with friends or create your own group for your organisation!                                                                                                        How is this different to other social media websites then? Myevent is about connecting people’s social lives and events all at the same place.  myventr.co will help find all the event details around your location and will also help avoid events clashing by simply searching the Event Calendar before creating an event."; 
[self.view addSubview:textView];
```